# C Flatten 2-D Array of Char* to 1-D

Tags: c, arrays, char, flatten

Say I have the following code:

```
char* array[1000]; // An array containing 1000 char*

// So, array[2] could be 'cat', array[400] could be 'space', etc.
```

Now, how could I flatten this array into 1-D? Is it possible to do this such that new_1D_array[2] would still be 'cat', new_1D_array[400] would still be 'space', etc.?

Comment: You'd need to know the size of the 2nd dimension of the array as it isn't specified above - unless they contain C strings, in which case it is possbile to flatten, but perhaps ot keep the same indexing into the list as you want.

Comment: Let's say each char* could be at most length 10. Would that count as a 2nd dimension?

Comment: "At most 10" means it could be a jagged array.  You need to know 100% for sure what the size of each element, not at most to treat it like a true 2-D array.  If it were length 8,6,7,9,5,10,etc. flattening becomes hard, unless you just stop at the end of the C string NUL char or 10 if it is not encountered (in which case you would need to terminate it somehow in your new array.)

Comment: Um, no. `char* array[1000]` is already a 1-D array of character pointers.

Comment: So, since char* array[1000] is already 1-D, does this mean it uses a single contiguous memory block?

Comment: The pointers are contiguous, but not necessarily the data within the pointers.

Comment: The array is a contiguous blocks of pointers, but each pointer is pointing to a totally different area in memory. Kind of like reading a phone book: the names on a page are contiguous, but the addresses of those people are all over the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a one-dimensional array of type `pointer-to-char`, with 1000 such elements. It's already 1D as far as arrays go, though it could be interpreted as a "jagged 2D array". If you want to convert this into one massive character array, you could do something like so, which requires calculating the size of the buffer you'll need to store it, and then flattening the array.

Note that if you opt to use `malloc` instead of `calloc`, you'll have to manually set the last character to `'\0'` or `0` so that the final result is a NULL-delimited C-style string, and not just a character array, as the latter of the two won't work with C string operations, and the former will.

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
        const char* array[] = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
        size_t length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(char*);

        int i;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
                printf("Element #%d - %s\n", i, array[i]);
                sum += strlen(array[i]) + 1;
        }
        sum++;  // Make room for terminating null character

        char* buf;
        if ((buf = calloc(sum, sizeof(char))) != NULL) {
                for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
                        memcpy(buf+count, array[i], strlen(array[i]));
                        count += strlen(array[i]) + 1;
                        buf[count-1] = '#';
                }
                printf("Output Buffer: %s\n", buf);
                printf("Buffer size:%d - String Length:%d\n", sum, strlen(buf));
                free(buf);
                buf = NULL;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

---

```
Element #0 - one
Element #1 - two
Element #2 - three
Element #3 - four
Output Buffer: one#two#three#four#
Buffer size:20 - String Length:19
```

Comment: @casualresearcher No problem. Feel free to post comments if you need help tweaking it.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer beat me to the puch and looks great, but I'll finish my thoughts here.

In this version every 11th byte of flatArray will contain the start of the strings from the original array, making it very easy to find the original strings from the ones before - i.e. string index 2 would start at `2*11 == index 22` and string 400 would start at `400 * 11 == index 4400`.  In this way, you would not need to iterate through the flat array counting terminators to find your old strings.  The cost of this being that the flat array takes a bit more memory than the original.

```
char* array[1000];

// Malloc new buffer
char *flatArray = malloc(length * 1100);

for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
{  
    strncpy(&flatArray[i * 11], array[i], 10);
    flatArray[i * 11 + 10] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Lol - way too slow. :)

Comment: Definitely a great example as well. Thank you for posting :)